# I want to access variable in dart

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access imageUrl variable into Scaffold's body.

```
class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _homeTopSliderData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("homeTopSliderData").snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _homeTopSliderData,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Something went wrong"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
querySnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            var imageUrl = data['imageUrl'];
          });
return Scaffold(
        body: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
        ),
      );
    });
```

}
}

It shows error when I use it as network image's url,
I am new to flutter and dart
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variable `imageUrl` is local, for that reason the `scaffold` can't access to that variable. To get more info refer to: https://toastguyz.com/dart/dart-variable-scope

It should work in the next way:

```
class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _homeTopSliderData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("homeTopSliderData").snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _homeTopSliderData,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot) {
          if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text("Something went wrong"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
          var imageUrl;
querySnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            imageUrl = data['imageUrl'];
          });
return Scaffold(
        body: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
        ),
      );
    });
} }
```

Comment: no it's not working in this way also...

Comment: after this it says url is null

Comment: simply tell me that how to fetch images from firestore and add them to courselSlider, I see many tutorials and solutions for this but no one able to do this

Answer (score 0):

You are streaming a collection, therefore, you will get a List of imageUrls (not 1, you could get up to 5 imageUrls). From your code, you are not using the list of imageUrls for anything, you are simply trying to use the last value of imageUrl. So, I do not think you want to stream a collection. I think you want a particular imageUrl.

To get a particular imageUrl, stream the document like this:

```
Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _homeTopSliderData =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("homeTopSliderData")
        // TODO: replace DOCUMENTID with your document id.
        .doc("DOCUMENTID")
        .snapshots();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream: _homeTopSliderData,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.hasError) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text("Something went wrong"),
          ),
        );
      } else if (querySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      }
      Map<String, dynamic> data = querySnapshot.data.data();
      print(data['imageUrl']);
      return Scaffold(
        body: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(data['imageUrl']),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

If you want to stream a collection (get all imageUrls in all documents) (**bad idea since you are obviously not expecting multiple imageUrls**), you can replace this part in your code:

```
var imageUrl;
querySnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(data['imageUrl']);
  if (data['imageUrl'] != null) {
    imageUrl = data['imageUrl'];
  }
});
return Scaffold(
  body: Image(
    image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
  ),
);
```